# change view's property from method of other class

Tags: iphone, methods

I'm trying to remotely adjust an object `myImageView`'s `alpha`to `0` of `MyViewController`class From Another class `Assistant`(it's a NSObject subclass).

in `Assistant.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class MyViewController;

@interface Assistant : NSObject {

    MyViewController *myViewController;
    UIImageView *button;

}
- (void)adjustAlpha:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *button;
```

in `Assistant.m`

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@implementation Assistant

@synthesize button;

- (id)init 
{
 self = [super init];
 if (self) 
 {
      myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
      NSLog(@"alloced?: %@", myViewController ? @"YES" : @"NO");
 }
 return self;
}

- (void)adjustAlpha:(id)sender
{
     NSLog(@"method called");
     myViewController.myImageView.alpha = 0;
}
```

the method did get called, But `myViewController.myImageView.alpha` didn't change, why? where i need to fix? thank you for reading ^_^

**Edit**

This is MyViewController class:

MyViewController.h

```
@class Assistant;

@class MyAppAppDelegate;

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate> 
{
   UIImageView *myImageView;
   Assistant *assistant;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *myImageView;
```

MyViewController.m

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "Assistant.h"

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize myImageView;


- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
    assistant = [[Assistant alloc] init];
    myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
    [self.view addSubview: myScrollView];


    myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"weather.png"]];
    myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(19, 54, 48, 48);
    myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [myScrollView addSubview:myImageView];



    //this button uses to call adjustAlpha
    assistant.button = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"]];  
    assistant.button.frame = CGRectMake(19, 126, 48, 48);
    assistant.button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[myScrollView addSubview:assistant.button];

    //here is how i call adjustAlpha:
    assistant.adjustAlphaTap =  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:assistant action:@selector(adjustAlpha:)];
    [assistant.button addGestureRecognizer:assistant.adjustAlphaTap];

}
```

this question got complex and need some experiments, so just hanging there, will make it clear when i have time. for developer met the same problems: declare the object you need to access in a singleton class, can be easily accessed from any other classes, and Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if `myImageView` is declared as a global scope variable (also called an iVar) in the .h file of your `MyViewController` class AND that it has a property of `(nonatomic, retain)` with a matching `@synthesize` in the .m.

If this sounds like what you're doing then can you please post the contents of your `MyViewController` h and m files.

Answer (score 1):

If you have everything defined like Thomas described, can you check if the `adjustAlpha` method is called on the main thread?